# API TOKEN Returns Status 200 ok but shows Login Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, token, plesk

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/PatientApi/FindPatient/{Regid}")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage FindPatient(int Regid)
{
    using (ApplicationDbContext LagEnt = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        try
        {
        var entity = LagEnt.Registrations.FirstOrDefault(reg => reg.RegistrationNo == Regid);
        if (entity != null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Patient Name:" + "" + entity.FirstName + " " + entity.LastName + " " + "Hospital no." + " " + entity.RegistrationNo);
        }
        else 
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Hospital No." + " " + Regid.ToString() + " " + " is not found.");
        }
        }
        catch(HttpResponseException ex)
        {
            return ex.Response;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Bearer Token Authorization for my API, It works when my connection string is pointing to my local database but when i changed the connection string to point to the shared server (i am using plesk hosting) The status is '200 ok' but shows the login page instead. The Token is correct but i don't know what might be the problem since it works well with my local database, I'd appreciate any help, Thanks.

[Postman Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBbvh.jpg)

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: Is "-" in the beginning part of the token?
Is your app a web API? The error message looks like an HTML page... Is that how it works normally when token is invalid? Sorry, it is hard to tell without seeing more of your app/code.

Comment: @despamigros I have Edited it to include the API code

Comment: @KehindeOgundeyi could you format this a little?

Comment: @SudipShrestha yes the '-' is part of the token and i have included the 'FindPatient' code.

Comment: @despamigros it has been edited

Comment: Could you please share relevant code from Startup.ConfigureServices?

Comment: What is your connection string look like? Can it be shared with critical info censored?

Comment: @SudipShrestha <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=x;Initial Catalog=x; user id=x;password=x;Integrated Security=false" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> This is the connection string, For the startup, I use    app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions); which is from .net Implemention, What baffles me is that it works when the connection string point to my Local database

Comment: "Use a local account to login" => Could also mean IIS App Pool Identity issue...
Is the working connection string to the local database using username+password or Integrated Security?

Comment: @SudipShrestha it is using integrated security

Comment: @SudipShrestha while i was using 'update database' to migrate the database to the shared hosting database, i got this error "The target principal name is incorrect.  Cannot generate SSPI context." so i had to set integrated security to false, could that be the problem?

Comment: ok. Things are making a little sense now. The entity framework CS code does not have any connection string hard coded accidentally, does it? Also, I am sure you tested the username/password from SSMS, correct?

Comment: Is this shared database production database? It is not the best idea to migrate database using ef like that... It seems easy but one mistake may delete your production data.

Comment: @SudipShrestha no it does not have, yes i have tested it in SSMS

Comment: @SudipShrestha yes it is the production db, there are no data yet, it is a new project

Comment: @KehindeOgundeyi what have you configured in you Startup.cs file?

Comment: @despa migros I have been able to resolve it, the issue was with plesk (the hosting site) ,I turned the authentication mode in the session settings from none to windows